# asymptotics of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let an monotonous increasing sequence $L_k$ be given, such that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \left(L_k b^{-k}\right)=0$ and $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \left(L_k a^{-k}\right)=\infty$, does it hold that for some $a<c<b$ we have $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left(L_k c^{-k}\right)=r$, where r is some finite number? If so, how could this be proved?

Thank you very much in advance for any ideas on the subject.

Comment: In fact it would already suffice, to show that $r_1\leq\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left(L_k c^{-k}\right)\leq r_2$

Comment: $L_k = k 2^k{}$.

Comment: @ Antonio Vargas: I beg your pardon, but what do you mean? The sequence $L_k$ is not $k2^k$?

Comment: I mean, consider the sequence $L_k = k 2^k$.  Then if $0 < a \leq 2 < b$ we have $$\lim_{k \to \infty} L_k b^{-k} = 0$$ and $$\lim_{k \to \infty} L_k a^{-k} = \infty,$$ so there is no $c$ for which $\lim_{k \to \infty} L_k c^{-k}$ is finite and nonzero.

Comment: I see more clearly now, you gave a counterexample, such that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left(L_k (b+\varepsilon)^{-k}\right)=0$ and $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left(L_k (b-\varepsilon)^{-k}\right)=\infty$. Thank you very much, but you should have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If such a limit $r$ exists, $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left(L_k c^{-k}\right)=r$

First, since $L_k$ is increasing, $0<c<1$

Let $\delta = \min L_{k+1}-L_{k}$

Because of the convergence and of the monotonous increasing, $\delta>0$

Let $L'$ the sequence such as $L'_{2k} = L_{2k}$ and $L'_{2k-1} = L_{2k}-\frac\delta2$

- $L'$ is a monotonous increasing sequence
- $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left(L'_k b^{-k}\right)=0$
- $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left(L'_k a^{-k}\right)=\infty$
- $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \left(L'_k c^{-k}\right)$ does not converge

Conclusion : $r$ and $c$ do not necessary exist