# Refining the asymptotics of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Assume that we have a monotonously increasing sequence $L_k$, such that $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\left(L_kb^{-k}\right)=0$ and $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\left(L_ka^{-k}\right)=\infty$, can we conclude that:

a) there exists $a\leq c\leq b$, such that $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\left(L_kc^{-k}\right)=0$ and $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\left(L_k(c-\varepsilon)^{-k}\right)=\infty$, and

b) that $L_k=Cc^k+o(c^k)$, where C is some constant?

Thank you very much in advance for any help. (This is a follow up to my earlier question here: [asymptotics of a sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712226/asymptotics-of-a-sequence))

Comment: No, we cannot: $$L_k = \frac{b^k}{\log (k+M)}$$ For any $b > 1$, you can choose $M$ so that the sequence is monotonically increasing.

Comment: But $\frac{1}{\log(k+M)}$ would still be $o(b^k)$, wouldn't it?

Comment: Ah, you changed to $a \leqslant c \leqslant b$. Then we need a different counterexample. Let $a < c < b$, and set $L_k = k\cdot c^k$ (assuming $c \geqslant 1$). Then $L_k\cdot x^{-k}\to 0 \iff x > c$ and $L_k\cdot x^{-k}\to \infty \iff x \leqslant c$.

Comment: As I understand your comment, this means that the above is correct?

Comment: If your $\lim_{k\to\infty} \bigl(L_k(c-\varepsilon)^{-k}\bigr) = \infty$ is supposed to mean "for every $\varepsilon > 0$...", then it's not correct. The above sequence gives a counterexample. What we have is that under the conditions $L_kb^{-k} \to 0$ and $L_ka^{-k}\to \infty$, there is a well-defined $c\in [a,b]$ such that $L_kx^{-k}\to 0$ for all $x > c$ and $L_kx^{-k}\to \infty$ for all $x < c$. $L_kc^{-k}$ can converge to $0$, converge to $0 < C < \infty$, converge to $\infty$, or not converge at all. Your statement ony covers the case of convergence to $0 \leqslant C < \infty$.

Comment: Ok, I think I understood now, I'm just not sure about the convergence to $\infty$ in the case $L_kc^{-k}$, please excuse my stubornness.

Comment: Well, for $L_k = k\cdot c^k$, we evidently have $L_kc^{-k} = k \to \infty$. Then we have $L_k \in o(x^k)$ for all $x > c$, but not $L_k \in O(c^k)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I got it!

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\ln n$, $a=1$, $b=2$. There is no $c$.